# Access PCL ViewModel from MainActivity in Xamarin.Droid

Tags: mvvm, xamarin

I am using a Xamarin.Forms Portable solution in VS2015. I bound my contentpage in the PCL to a ViewModel using MVVM Light. If i now change one of my properties in the ViewModel it would update the UI on Android, IOS and UWP. However, i am stuck at a point where i am not sure how to realize updating the ViewModel property.

In my droid project MainActivity i am registering a new intent, using the inherited `OnNewIntent` from Activity. As soon as this `OnNewIntent` is called i want to change properties in the ViewModel, for example a `public string example`. I cannot simply do it using

```
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
vm.example = "Hi from Android";
```

as i then create a new instance of the ViewModel and my DataBinding is referencing another instance. So what is a proper way of doing this? I thought about using DependencyInjection in the getter of my ViewModel properties, like

```
public string example 
{get {%using dependency injection here to get the string from Android }}
```

but then i also have to notify the ViewModel that the binding has to be updated when `OnNewIntent` is called in the MainActivity.

So i would be very thankful for any suggestions how to organize this in a good way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the view model by writing custom renderer for the view you have loaded in the content page. For instance, you load a Label in a content page. Then you can write a custom renderer for that label and get the view model as like below,

```
class CustomRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    public ViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        var label = sender as Label;
        if (label != null)
        {
            ContentPage page = label.Parent as ContentPage;
            ViewModel = page.BindingContext as ViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

Please ensure to add the below attribute above the namespace in the custom renderer class,

[assembly:ExportRendererAttribute(typeof(Label),typeof(CustomRenderer))]

Then you can access that ViewModel property(which is nothing but the ViewModel in your pcl) in MainActivity by just creating an instance for CustomRenderer class as like below,

CustomRenderer renderer = new CustomRenderer();

renderer.ViewModel.example = "XXX";

I hope this way will help you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I did it now in this way:

I created a static class `public static class MyClass` in the PCL project which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. From my `OnNewIntent` in the MainActivity I am setting the property `public static string example` in `MyClass`. In the setter of this property I am calling `PropertyChanged` which is noticed in the ViewModel. There I use  `RaisePropertyChanged("example")` and in the getter of the ViewModel property `example` I am using `get { return My Class.example; }`. So basically I am simply using a static Model (or static properties in my Model, doesn't need to be static itself) of my ViewModel which notifies the ViewModel when something changes. The same properties can then be set from the iOS or UWP projects and their UI references the same ViewModel... Do you think it is a good solution?